# has_one relation adding up another object in present object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I have a model punch which has belongs_to :user relation.But when ever i call a punch object i am getting user object combined with punch object how can i remove user object from punch object on calling a punch object?

```
2.5.1 :001 > Punch.last
 => #<Punch _id: 5dc28149d807465afb0750b2, created_at: 2019-11-06 08:16:09 UTC, updated_at: 2019-11-06 08:16:09 UTC, deleted_at(deleted_at): nil, punch_in_datetime: 2019-11-06 08:16:06 UTC, punch_in_latitude: 17.7262481, punch_in_longitude: 83.3065046, punch_in_timezone: "+05:30", punch_out_datetime: nil, punch_out_latitude: nil, punch_out_longitude: nil, punch_out_timezone: nil, time_in: true, punch_id: "57d09dc3-367a-435b-9c3c-9b5bf8a29cdb", late_timeout_reason_id: nil, distance_travelled: 0.0, duration: nil, _keywords: ["367a", "435b", "57d09dc3", "9b5bf8a29cdb", "9c3c", "aravind", "com", "gmail", "nikhil"], user_id: BSON::ObjectId('5dbff700d807466d0660fba2')>
```

Comment: What do you mean that you get user combined with punch? There is only `user_id` in the listing you sent. Also it seems that you're using mongoid, not active record.

Comment: Yes, found out why User object is getting added its because of serializer  where we have added ```has_one :user```. Anyway thanks for your quick response @mrzasa & @rajdeep

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Punch` model `belongs_to` `User`, that means `Punch` object will have `user_id`, in your `Punch` object example, I can only see the `user_id`, which is correct.

It's not `user` object, it's `user_id`, and that is a `BSON` object in `Mongoid`.